# Write a Python script named ten-sum-even.py which outputs the sum of only the even integers encountered

Tags: python

My Attempt:

```
n = 10

total = 0

i = 0
while i < n:
    if i % 2 == 0:
    print(total)
    
else:
print(i)

total = total + int(input())
i = i + 1
```

Terminal is still counting every number

Comment: What's the output? Is the formatting exactly right, the indentation looks wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake:
You are on right track but just printing in case its even wont help. You actually need to add that number to the total sum so far as:

```
n = 10
total = 0
i = 0
while i < n:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        total+=i
    else:
        print(i)
    i+=2
print(total)
```

Or simply:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(n) if i%2==0]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = 10
total = 0

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        total = total + i
print("Total of even numbers is " + total)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n = 10
sum = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sum += i
print (sum)
```